# Multiple markers in flask google map api

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps, flask

I'm creating a flask app and try to fetch coordinates from mysql DB, the database has latitude and longitude infomation, I'd like to show all of markers on the page with the lat/lng and tend to using js to add markers, don't know why it doesn't work. Any helps appreciated.

using flask sqlalchemy to get lat/lng info

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function initMap() {
            var latlng = {lat: -37.8253632, lng: 144.1404107}; // THIS IS CENTER OF THE MAP
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: latlng
            });

            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', addMarkers);

            function addMarkers() {
                {% for CarD in page_data %}
                  var point = {lat: {{ CarD.lat }}, lng: {{ CarD.lng }} };
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: point,
                    map: map,
                    title: '!'
                });
                    {% endfor %}

                marker['infowindow'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: '<div id="content" style="text-align: center"></div>'
                }); // info of the point

            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jinja templates are processed on the server side so putting the python variables in javascript only works if the js is in your template (as in you have the html and js in the same .html file). Additionally, i would discourage you from mixing the code. I would recommend you make an ajax call and receive a json response with your points. In flask you can do something like this

```
@app.route('/api/coordinates) 
def coordinates():
  addresses = session.query(Coordinates)#however you query your db
  all_coods = [] # initialize a list to store your addresses
  for add in addresses:
     address_details = {
     "lat": add.lat, 
     "lng": add.lng, 
     "title": add.title}
     all_coods.append(address_details)
  return jsonify({'cordinates': all_coods})
```

then in your javascript you can call this endpoint then process the json object (I like to use fetch for my ajax calls)

```
var map;
function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91722, 151.23064),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

//variable to hold your endpoint
var coodAddresses = 'https://yoursite.com/api/coordinates';
//an array to hold your cordinates
var locations = [];
//Using fetch to process the ajax call 
// if you use fetch, besure to include the source below this line in your template
//<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.js"></script>
fetch(coodAddresses)
.then(function(response) {
 return response.text();
 }).then(function(body) {
 var obj = JSON.parse(body);
 var myAdd = {};
 var addresses = obj.cordinates;
 var l = addresses.length;
 for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
 myAdd = {
      position: {
          lat: parseFloat(obj.cordinates[i].lat),
          lng: parseFloat(obj.cordinates[i].lng)
                },
          title: obj.cordinates[i].title,
           };
 locations.push(myAdd);
}
locations.forEach(function(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            title: feature.title,
            map: map
          });
        });

}).catch(function() {
// if the ajax call fails display an error in an info window
                var pos = {
                    lat: lat,
                    lng: lng
                };
                infoWindow.setMap(map);
                infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                infoWindow.setContent('An error occurred, we are unable to retreive cordinates.');

            });
      }
```

I hope you find this useful. If your points are not near each other, you may need to make sure the bounds include all of them